# How to save and read data from JSON

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to save a million data to a JSON file in my NodeJS application. The main idea is to save a grid of 1000x1000 pixels as an array with the x,y position and a color id so each pixel has a coordinate and a color. My actual code to generate an example :

So I have a function to generate data and using fs.writeFile() I can save it.

```
//resetPos('test.json');
function resetPos(path) {
    let data = [];
    for (let y = 1; y <= 1000; y++){
        data.push([]);
    }
    data.forEach(function(e, i){
        for (let x = 1; x <= 1000; x++) {
            e.push([
                "x": x,
                "y": i,
                "color": "#cccccc"
            ]);
        }
    });
    fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(data), function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
    });
    console.log(data);
}
let global_data = fs.readFileSync("test.json");
console.log(global_data[0]);
```

When I read the file, it shows "91". I've tried using .toJSON() and .toString() but didn't go as I want. I looking do get an x,y coordinate as data[y][x];

Comment: What is e? That variable isn't defined anywhere and you just start pushing ["none"] into it. Also, data doesn't seem to have anything in it at all besides a thousand empty arrays.

Comment: e is defined as Element in function(e, i), It gets the selected element of foreach to push it into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there are two ways to read a `.json` file in Node.js.

Your first option is to use the `require` function, which you normally use to import `.js` files, but you can use it for `.json` files as well:

```
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
```

The advantage of this approach is that you get back the contents of the `.json` file as a JavaScript object or array, already parsed. The disadvantage of this approach is that you can not reload the file within the current process if something has changed, since `require` caches the contents of any loaded file, and you are always given back the cached value.

Your second option is exactly the opposite: It allows you to reload things, but it requires you to parse the file on your own. For that, you use the `fs` module's `readFile` function:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./package.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err, data) => {
  const packageJson = JSON.parse(data);

  // ...
});
```

If you want to use `async` and `await`, and if you use the `util.promisify` function of Node.js, you can also write this in a synchronous way, but keep the asynchronous code:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      { promisify } = require('util');

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

(async () => {
  const data = await readFile('./package.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
  const packageJson = JSON.parse(data);

  // ...
})();
```

Apart from that, there is also the `fs.readFileSync` function, which works in a synchronous way, but you should stay away from that one for performance reasons of your software.

For writing a JSON file, your only option is to use the `writeFile` function of the `fs` module, which works basically the same as its `readFile` counterpart:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const packageJson = { /* ... */ };
const data = JSON.parse(packageJson);

fs.writeFile('./package.json', data, { encoding: 'utf8' }, err => {
  // ...
});
```

Again, you can use the `util.promisify` function as mentioned above to make things work with `async` and `await`, or you could use the synchronous `fs.writeFileSync` function (which, again, I would not recommend).

Answer (score 0):

You can generally read in a JSON file with the **require** method of Node.

Example: `const myJSON = requrie('./file.json')` myJSON will hold the JSON data from file.json as a normal Javascript Object.

You can write a JSON file yourself, using:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
fs.writeFile('file.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
```